# Update many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework throws a lambda expression error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have these models

```
public class Admin
{
    public Admin()
    {
       this.course = new HashSet<Courses>();
    } 

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Courses> course { get; set; }
}

public class Courses
{
    public Courses()
    {
        this.admin = new HashSet<Admin>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Admin> admin { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my controller method to update

```
public ActionResult Admins( Admin rec, IList<int> CourseId)
{      
   if (rec.ID > 0)   // edit
   {
       var dbrec = db.Admins.Include("Courses").Where(s => s.ID == rec.ID).FirstOrDefault<Admin>();
      dbrec.DisplayName = rec.DisplayName;

      var deletedCourses = dbrec.course.Except(rec.course, cours => cours.ID).ToList<Courses>();
    }
}
```

I face a problem here in this line of code `cours => cours.ID`.

Error message

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type IEqualityComparer because it is not a delegate type

Could anyone tell me why I get this error?

I'm following this tutorial

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-many-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: You wrong using  `Except()`.  `var deletedCourses = dbrec.course.Except(rec.course).ToList<Courses>();` this get all _except_ `rec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `Except()` look like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
IEnumerable<TSource> second)
```

So you can use it

`var deletedCourses = dbrec.course.Except(rec.course).ToList<Courses>();`
 this get all `course` *except* `rec`

Why you get Error?? Simple you need use the code above instead your or use extension
for `Except()` method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other,                                                                           Func<T, TKey> getKey)
{
    return from item in items
            join otherItem in other on getKey(item)
            equals getKey(otherItem) into tempItems
            from temp in tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ReferenceEquals(null, temp) || temp.Equals(default(T))
            select item;

}
```

> we have used following extension method to compare values from two lists and return entities from one list which is not present into second list. Comparison happening based on passed function: